# if & else statements

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I'm looking for some help with a little problem I'm having. Basically i have a "if & else" statement in my app but I want to add another "if" statement that checks for a file then for certain line of text in that file. But I am unsure of how to do this.

- on "if" check if file exists
- on "if" check if file exists but DOES NOT contain a certain line of text
- on "else" do something

here is what i i have

```
if(file.exists()) { 
                        do this
} else {
                        do this
}
```

Comment: Open the file for reading.  If it does not exist you'll get an exception. Then, once the file is open, read it, looking for the line.

Or alternatively, just grep it from the command line ;-)

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you either need:

```
if (file.exists() && readFileAndCheckForWhatever(file)) {
    // File exists and contains the relevant word
} else {
    // File doesn't exist, or doesn't contain the relevant word
}
```

or

```
if (file.exists()) {
    // Code elided: read the file...
    if (contents.contains(...)) {
        // File exists and contains the relevant word
    } else {
        // File exists but doesn't contain the relevant word
    }
} else {
    // File doesn't exist
}
```

or reversing the logic of the previous one to flatten it

```
if (!file.exists()) {
    // File doesn't exist
} else if (readFileAndCheckForWhatever(file)) {
    // File exists and contains the relevant word       
} else {
    // File exists but doesn't contain the relevant word
}
```

Comment: the second one looks like what i need but (contents.contains(...)) pulls up the error "contents cannot be resolved"

Comment: @Leigh8347: Well yes, you'll have to write some code yourself. That's what the "code elided" bit is about - reading the file.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am missing something, couldn't you just be using `else if`?

`else if((file.exists())&&(!file.contains(Whatever))) { ... }`

`File.contains` would need to be exchanged for a function that actually checks the file, but you get the idea.

Comment: No.  If the file exists, she wants to do something.

Comment: @TonyEnnis Bummer. I really have to learn to read the question properly, I understood it as "either file exists and does not contain XYZ, or it exists and contains it, else...", but it would not make too much sense to do it with an `else if`. Hmm, I really do need to get some sleep, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean something like:

```
if(file.exists() && containsLine(file))
{
  // do something
}
else
{
  // do something else
}

public boolean containsLine(File f)
{
  // do the checking here
}
```